# How do autoencoders reconstruct images/color?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am abit confused by how autoencoders are able to reconstruct colors in images. According to me a CNN has feature detectors that convert the image into a sequence of feature or activation maps. These activation map corrospond to the degree of presense of a structural feature. Then how is the color information preserved in autoencoders if it is not a structural feature? To me the color information gets lost very quickly but most visuals of autoencoders show they preserve color very well.

Answer (score 1):

Autoencoders do not differ from any other kind of neural network applied to images (e.g. [convolutional neural networks](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)). Images are stored on computers on many formats, one of the popular ones is to have the image splited to three layers, for the red, green, and blue channels, where the final color that you see is the combination of the values from the three layers. When working with such data, neural networks usually also keep the information stored in three layers, for each basic color. This happens in dense, convolutional, and any other kind of layer. Same applies to autoencoders, that are defined in terms on the same building blocks as any other kind of neural network.

Moreover, even if you flattened the layers, there is no reason why network should loose any information. If they are able to learn spatial relations, smiles, letters, digits, animal shapes, shoe shapes, and a lot of other kind of things, I see no reason why color should be any special.

Comment: Because of the interpretation of cnn filters that look for similarity thus reducing the original image into a series of similarity maps. How are these similarity maps converted to an image of full color in the decoder is my question. Color is special due to its non-structure

Comment: @RahulDeora I don't know what you mean by "non-structure", but the three numbers for R,G,B colors for each pixel are a structure for me. The color is passed through the R,G,B encoding.

Comment: I am asking how is color preserved in the similarity or activation maps that condense points overlapping the filter through a dot product operation.  (By structure I meant no consistent structure like edge/circle)

Comment: @RahulDeora usually each layer of NNs for color images has (n,m,k,3) dimensions, where m,n,k can differ but the last one stays unchanged, it is for each of the R,G,B color layers of the image. However in the end, for autoencoder you can have any structure, just need to return three R,G,B values for each pixel and it doesn't really make a difference how you represent it in intermediate layers.

Comment: I understand that, but don't you see how the dot product operation looses alot of information? It is not a 1-1 operation. If you are saying at the end they just return a RGB based on activation maps, it means they compute the color of the object based on its structure which is clearly not true as AE's work for objects never seen before. So the color is propogated through activation maps. " it doesn't really make a difference how you represent it in intermediate layers", I mean, thats what I'm trying to understand... how the network learns

Comment: @RahulDeora neural networks are just a bunch of dot products and other operations on arrays of numbers. Learning colours does not differ from learning any other kind of features. It is same as if you asked "How does NN learn that cars need to have wheels?". They just do. I'm sorry but I don't know how can I help you with your confusion.